# Syntax error in MySQL but with correct syntax when creating ROLE

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, syntax-error, roles

I am getting a syntax error:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ROLE 'administrator', 'developer'' at line 1

I just set up MySQL on my Ubuntu 16 box with the latest mysql. I created a user called sqluser just fine, I just can't seem to do other things without getting a syntax error. This is really frustrating. I have looked over the docs and the Intrawebs. I can't seem to find an answer. I am typing everything in correctly:

```
mysql> CREATE ROLE 'administrator', 'developer';
```

Could someone please help?

Comment: The error doesn't match the SQL you shared.

Comment: I see that CREATE ROLE is not available in the Context that I'm trying to use it. I just need to figure out what that Context is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking at the version of MySQL which is 14.14, but I should be looking at the Distribution, which is 5.7.31. It is not 8, so that means I don't have direct access to create and grant roles.